# SQLiteAsyncConnection missing assembly reference

Tags: android, xamarin, android-sqlite

I have installed `PCLStorage` in `newget` package and added Interface `IsqlliteDB.cs` and implemented in android project `SqlDb.cs`. When I execute the project I get the following error.

[image]

Can someone Help me Out?

Comment: Please show your codes.